# Timer and DatagramSockets java

Tags: java, udp

I am implementing a callback function between clients and a server.

Client registers itself with the server and when an event happens, the server will send a datagrampacket to the client to inform the client about the event.

Client will be blocked through the whole listening period, specified by the user

When it is blocked, it will enter into this loop to continue listening to the server for callback.

```
while (waiting) {
    aSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
    aSocket.receive(reply);
    String replyString = new String(reply.getData()).trim();
    System.out.println(replyString);
    buffer = new byte[1000];
    reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
}
```

I have coded a timer with a timertask that changes the value of waiting from true to false after the listening period is over.

My problem is I would like the client to stop listening once the listening period is over. However, even if I use the timer, the client will be blocked at

```
aSocket.receive(reply);
```

Does anyone here know how can I skip this code and exit out of the loop?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

> The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an
>   infinite timeout.

So, when you use 0 for `setSoTimeout()`, it just blocks on receive().

Comment: It was intended because if I set a timeout, say 5000ms, if the server sends a message at 5001ms, the client would raise an timeoutexception instead of listening to the message.

Comment: yeah, you will have to set a suitable timeout and handle `TimeoutException`, because of the blocking nature of `receive()`. If you are familiar with java NIO, there are some non-blocking options.

Comment: I will try your method. Not very sure with java NIO. don't think my teacher would want us to go that way.